# Using IDispatchImpl with an Unregistered Interface in an MFC+ATL EXE

Tags: visual-c++, com, mfc, atl, visual-c++-2010

I started the project as an MFC Application (for the GUI..), and later added support for ATL.

I then coded a simple ATL-COM object implementing a non registered dual interface using IDispatchImpl, with the 0xfff for Major and Minor, to tell ATL to load the TLB from the EXE.

I skip some details, but at the end, after some debugging I found that the CComTypeInfoHolder::GetTI implementation in atlcom.h was NOT trying to load the TLB from the EXE, but was searching it in the registry. Reason : a m_plibid variable was NOT corresponding to the DECLARE_LIBID macro use in my ATL::CAtlMfcModule declaration.

After some googling I found [Bug: CAtlMfcModule::InitLibId() not called](http://computer-programming-forum.com/77-vc-atl/6a0c39b3bf25ecfe.htm) and added a call to InitLibId in my module CTOR.

Works fine, now.

Question: Is that a known bug? with a known fix? I am not confortable with my workaround of such an old bug. Is there another way of dealing with that?

UPDATE: additional information, as an answer states there is no bug...

[IDispatchImpl Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/494h01te%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

By **default**, the **IDispatchImpl** class looks up the type information for
T **in the registry**. To implement an unregistered interface, you can use
the IDispatchImpl class **without accessing the registry** by using a
predefined version number. If you create an IDispatchImpl object that
has **0xFFFF as the value for wMajor and 0xFFFF as the value for wMinor**,
the IDispatchImpl class retrieves the type library **from the .dll file
instead of the registry.**

Excerpt from `CComTypeInfoHolder::GetTI` Implementation in `atlcom.h`:

```
if (InlineIsEqualGUID( CAtlModule::m_libid, *m_plibid) &&
                       m_wMajor == 0xFFFF &&
                       m_wMinor == 0xFFFF ) {
    TCHAR szFilePath[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD dwFLen = ::GetModuleFileName(_AtlBaseModule.GetModuleInstance(), szFilePath, MAX_PATH);
    [...]
    hRes = LoadTypeLib(pszFile, &pTypeLib);
} else {
    [...]
    hRes = LoadRegTypeLib(*m_plibid, m_wMajor, m_wMinor, lcid, &pTypeLib);
```

So, it seems clear to me that there is an *advertised behavior*: use 0xffff for minor and major and ATL will try to load the typelib from module, not from registry, provided that your CAtlModule::m_libid is up todate. How is CAtlModule::m_libid expected to be be up to date? By using the `DECLARE_LIBID` macros. How does work that macro? by defining a static `InitLibId` function, which set up `CAtlModule::m_libid`.

The bug: when your module derives from `ATL::CAtlMfcModule`, the defined InitLibId function is NOT called (as ATL::CAtlMfcModule is not a class template)

Comment: I don't see how it is a bug. The interface is not registered, so you have to hint `CComTypeInfoHolder` on your own. Base classes *could* help you making second attempt to load from private unregistered type library, but they don't have to do it.

Comment: @RomanR. That's a bug, imho. The DECLARE_LIBID macro is precisely intended to hint CComTypeInfoHolder, but is useless if the generated InitLibId function is never called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, if you are using `-1` for major/minor versions, then is is assumed that type information would be taken from the binary. This however does not work with MFC projects: `DECLARE_LIBID` only works up to `CAtlMfcModule` class but not its descendants.

A quick fix might be like this, in atlbase.h:

```
//class CAtlMfcModule :
//  public ATL::CAtlModuleT<CAtlMfcModule>

template <typename T>
class CAtlMfcModuleT : 
    public ATL::CAtlModuleT<T>
```

and then in your project:

```
//class CMFCApplication1Module :
//  public ATL::CAtlMfcModule

class CMFCApplication1Module :
    public ATL::CAtlMfcModuleT<CMFCApplication1Module>
```

If you post it on [MS Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/) as a bug, you can leave a link here for others to go upvote the bug.